# Oracle OGG-00435 - Must be PURGE, APPEND, RESTART, MEGABYTES or MAXFILES

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I am deploying Oracle Golden Gate.

When starting data pump,the program throw an error:

```
Oracle OGG-00435 - Must be PURGE, APPEND, RESTART, MEGABYTES or MAXFILES.
```

The detail error line:

```
2014-12-07 14:22:30  ERROR   OGG-00435  Must be PURGE, APPEND, FORMAT RELEASE, M
EGABYTES or MAXFILES.
```

The command:**`View report pump001`** output:

```
***********************************************************************
               Oracle GoldenGate Capture for SQL Server
 Version 12.1.2.0.1 17597485 OGGCORE_12.1.2.0.T2_PLATFORMS_131206.0309
 Windows x64 (optimized), Microsoft SQL Server on Dec  6 2013 12:32:54

Copyright (C) 1995, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.


                    Starting at 2014-12-07 14:22:30
***********************************************************************

Operating System Version:
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 , on x64
Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Process id: 15900

Description:

***********************************************************************
**            Running with the following parameters                  **
***********************************************************************

2014-12-07 14:22:30  INFO    OGG-03059  Operating system character set identifie
d as GBK.

2014-12-07 14:22:30  INFO    OGG-02695  ANSI SQL parameter syntax is used for pa
rameter parsing.
EXTRACT PUMP001
PASSTHRU
RMTHOST XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, MGRPORT 7809, compress
NUMFILES 5000
DYNAMICRESOLUTION
RMTTRAIL ./DIRDAT/R3,EXTRACT PUMP001

Source Context :
  SourceModule            : [er.extrout]
  SourceID                : [er/extrout.c]
  SourceFunction          : [get_outfile_params]
  SourceLine              : [3237]
  ThreadBacktrace         : [13] elements
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\gglo
g.dll(?CreateMessage@CMessageFactory@@QEAAPEAVCMessage@@PEAVCSourceContext@@IZZ+
0x886) [0x000007FEED1A09D6]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\gglo
g.dll(?_MSG_ERR_STARTUP_BADARG_OUTFILE_OPTION_INVALID@@YAPEAVCMessage@@PEAVCSour
ceContext@@W4MessageDisposition@CMessageFactory@@@Z+0x31) [0x000007FEED14ED81]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\extr
act.exe(<ataSync\GGSCISync\extract.exe) [0x000000013FE02E39]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\extr
act.exe(<ataSync\GGSCISync\extract.exe) [0x000000013FE033ED]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\extr
act.exe(ERCALLBACK+0x12125) [0x000000013FE50585]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\extr
act.exe(ERCALLBACK+0x385ee) [0x000000013FE76A4E]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\extr
act.exe(_ggTryDebugHook+0x111b3) [0x000000013FF3DCD3]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\extr
act.exe(_ggTryDebugHook+0x10610) [0x000000013FF3D130]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\extr
act.exe(_ggTryDebugHook+0x1105f) [0x000000013FF3DB7F]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\extr
act.exe(ERCALLBACK+0x39349) [0x000000013FE777A9]]
                          : [E:\JsptpdCollabrationSystem\DataSync\GGSCISync\extr
act.exe(??0_Mutex@std@@QEAA@W4_Uninitialized@1@@Z+0x436) [0x0000000140082BE2]]
                          : [C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll(BaseThreadInitThun
k+0xd) [0x0000000077AA652D]]
                          : [C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlUserThreadStart+0x
21) [0x0000000077BDC521]]

2014-12-07 14:22:30  ERROR   OGG-00435  Must be PURGE, APPEND, FORMAT RELEASE, M
EGABYTES or MAXFILES.

2014-12-07 14:22:30  ERROR   OGG-01668  PROCESS ABENDING.
```

And this is my data pump config:

```
EXTRACT PUMP001

PASSTHRU

RMTHOST XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, MGRPORT 7809, compress

NUMFILES 5000

DYNAMICRESOLUTION

RMTTRAIL ./DIRDAT/R3,EXTRACT PUMP001

TABLE dbo.*;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oracle official document give the reason cause the problem.

[Oracle GG error list](http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GMESG/oggus.htm)

```
OGG-00435: Must be PURGE, APPEND, FORMAT RELEASE, MEGABYTES or MAXFILES
Cause: An invalid argument was specified for EXTTRAIL, EXTFILE, RMTTRAIL, or RMTFILE.
Action: See the Oracle GoldenGate reference guide for valid options for the specified parameters.
```

Just verify the RMTTAIL parameter is correct.

```
RMTTRAIL ./DIRDAT/R3
```

And exec

```
ADD EXTTRAIL ./DIRDAT/L1, EXTRACT EXT001
```

command.